# Some PDF are partially displayed in Google Docs Viewer

Tags: google-drive, pdf

I have a web application where people can upload PDF files and I'm reviewing it online with Google Docs Viewer API, from a back-end web application. I can get many different PDF sources, because of that.

Some PDF are not correctly displayed: some text is missing. I can see the missing text when I open the PDF file with an "offline" PDF viewer, say Adobe Reader.

Any advice on this?

How to understand/debug/modify the PDF on-the-fly to make it OK?

I found an example of an incorrect PDF, the "file" command says it's a 1.4 PDF version. Google Docs shows correctly some 1.7 files I have. I first thought it could be related to a very recent PDF version, but it seems not.
(I read [Which versions of the PDF standard does Google Docs support?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25623/which-versions-of-the-pdf-standard-does-google-docs-support) before)
So what?

I can provide someone with an incorrect file if needed.

Comment: any idea someone?

Comment: I guess it's not very helpful right now, but you can compare the same pdf in different versions and possibly different export settings, and by eliminating understand which versions are supported.